# Will over 1000 301 redirects slow down my site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've updated my site links to use pretty URLs instead of query strings.

```
Old URL: https://digimoncard.io/deck/?deckid=1241
New URL: https://digimoncard.io/deck/green-otk-1241
```

Both URLs can be visited without a 404 but I plan on adding 301 redirects to my htaccess like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 https://digimoncard.io/deck/?deckid=1241 https://digimoncard.io/deck/green-otk-1241
```

Part of my concern is the number of redirects needed (will be **1218** exactly). Will this potentially slow down the site/server due to having to query each of these on every page load?

My other solution is to potentially leave it alone and let google index the new URLs and overtime let the query string ones stale out.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "opinion based" - my feeling is that you're asking "does it slow down _so much that I care_?" and we can't help you with that. You'll have to measure if _and how much_ it slows you down and determine if it's acceptable or not. _You_ will have to balance the value of redirects with the cost of speed impact (if at all)

Comment: Maybe also look into https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html (specifically `dbm: DBM Hash File`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1218 redirect directives in `.htaccess` shouldn't cause a noticeable/significant delay, however there are other issues with your suggestion and this can be greatly optimised to avoid any additional overhead...

> ...having to query each of these on every page load?

It's not just "every page load", but potentially *every request*. All static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc.) will trigger the same set of directives (unless they are hosted away from the application server).

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> Redirect 301 https://digimoncard.io/deck/?deckid=1241 https://digimoncard.io/deck/green-otk-1241
> ```

This won't work. The mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches the URL-path only, it does not match the query string (or scheme+hostname), so the above directive will simply fail to match and do nothing. (`RewriteEngine` is also part of mod_rewrite, not mod_alias.)

In order to match the query string you need to use mod_rewrite with an additional *condition* to check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^deckid=(1241)$
RewriteRule ^deck/$ /green-otk-%1 [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference contains `1241` (captured from the preceding *CondPattern*) - this simply saves repetition (that could potentially introduce bugs). Unless of course you are generating these directives automatically.

---

#### Don't use `.htaccess` - use your application logic instead

However, ideally, you would not be doing these redirects in `.htaccess` to begin with. It would be far more optimal to do these in your application logic (ideally when your site determines that the result would trigger a 404 - although that does not happen in your case). By placing these directives in `.htaccess` you are prioritising the "redirects" at the expense of normal site traffic. By implementing these redirects *later* (in your application) you prioritise normal site traffic.

Since I assume you are using a front-controller to route your URLs this should be relatively trivial to implement. (You only process the redirect logic when a request comes in that matches the old URL format.)

---

#### Optimised .htaccess version

However, you could greatly optimise this if deciding to go the `.htaccess` route if all your old URLs follow the same format... you could internally rewrite any request that uses the format `/deck/?deckid=<number>` to a subdirectory (assuming all your old URLs use this format). You then have another `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory that processes all the 1218 redirects. This way, you only have a single directive in your main `.htaccess` file, that is processed on every request and the redirect logic (in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file) is only processed when it needs to be.

This avoids the overhead of having 1000+ redirect directives in the main `.htaccess` file.

The directives in the subdirectory `.htaccess` file can also be simplified since we can rewrite the request to move the query string to the URL-path to avoid the additional *condition* later.

For example, at the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite the request for (what looks like) an old URL
# ...to the "/redirect-old" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^deckid=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^deck/$ redirect-old/%1 [L]
```

All URLs of the form `/deck/?deckid=<number>` are internally rewritten to `/redirect-old/<number>`...

Then, in `/redirect-old/.htaccess` you have *simplified* "redirect" directives like the following that match against the *rewritten* URL:

```
# /redirect-old/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect old URLs
RewriteRule ^1241$ /deck/green-otk-$0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^1234$ /deck/foo-$0 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^4321$ /deck/bar-$0 [R=301,L]
:
```

These directives match the rewritten URL, ie. `/redirect-old/<number>` and redirect accordingly.

The `$0` backreference in each case is simply the URL-path (ie. *number*) that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. (Saves repetition - as mentioned above.)

Comment: Doing it in my PHP application logic actually makes much more sense (I really overlooked this) and is now implemented without any perceivable slowdown. I tested the optimized .htaccess version too which also worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may slow down but not necessarily. If your .htaccess doesn't contain like 10k or more redirects, it should be fine. But on a precautionary side, you can always use files with less size and remove unnecessary redirects and let google index the URLs.

You can refer this link for more information
https://www.matthewedgar.net/do-redirects-add-to-website-speed/#htaccessredirectsspeed